# Error while downloading package "Export" in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download package "Export" in R but I am receiving this error message every time:

> Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
>     unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018g.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin'
>   ERROR: dependencies ‘flextable’, ‘rgl’, ‘openxlsx’ are not available for package ‘export’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/export’

I have tried other solutions:

Comment: Did you try installing `flextable`, `rgl` and `openxlsx` before installing `Export`?

Comment: No, I have installed any of these packages.